# Can't change value of BOOL from another class, IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

I encounter a simple problem , I am trying to change the bool value of a class from another class but it is not happening, it  returns `NO`.

//before pushing other viewcontroller

```
-(IBAction)editWOD
{
    self.editGirlController= [[AddGirlsView alloc] init];
    self.editGirlController.isEditModeON=YES;
    self.editGirlController.editgirls=girls;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editModeGirls" sender:self];
}
```

AddGirlsView .h

```
@interface AddGirlsView : UIViewController
{
    BOOL isEditModeON;

}
@property BOOL isEditModeON;
```

AddGirlsView .m

```
@synthesize isEditModeON;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if (isEditModeON==NO) {
        NSLog(@"Edit Mode is OFF");
    }
    else{
        [self populateViewOnEdit];
    }


}
```

Whats wrong with the code?

+++++++++ANSWER ADDED+++++++++++++++++

thanks to Joel here is the answer

```
-(IBAction)editWOD
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"editModeGirls" sender:self];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"editModeGirls"])
    {
        AddGirlsView *editGirlController  = [segue destinationViewController];
        editGirlController.isEditModeON=YES;
        editGirlController.editgirls=girls;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is that you alloc and init AddGirlsView. When you perform a segue it is probably re-instantiating another AddGirlsView. You should be setting this variable in prepareForSegue.

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"editGirlsMode"]) {
    [segue.destinationViewController setIsEditModeOn:YES];
    [segue.destinationViewController setEditGirls:girls];
}
```

Comment: @Firo Please See my Question http://stackoverflow.com/q/35885251/3378413 and give me some suggestion to solve my issue.

Answer (score -4):

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isEditModeON;
```

Comment: Not really a descriptive answer

Comment: Making the property nonatomic won't make any difference in this situation.