# Boolean Variable's value not change dismissViewControllerAnimated From Child to Parent in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, ios9, boolean-expression, viewdidappear

I am not a beginner but I can't figure out this silly issue. I have Two View Controllers For Example **Parent** and **Child** are classes. **Parent** is a base class and **child** is a sub class But I can't Inherited any data except these bool.

In Parent Class I use one `BOOL` Variable which I declare in **Parent.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isChange;
```

After that I synthesis this variable and initialize default **False** in `viewDidLoad`

```
isChange = FALSE;
```

Now, I use this variable in **Child** Class and I Change the value to `True`

```
Parent.isChange = TRUE;
```

Before this change I also `alloc` and `init` **Parent** Class in **Child** class.

```
Parent = [[Parent alloc] init];
```

But the issue is when I Dismiss this Class and go to **Parent** Class `isChange` value not change.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I checked in **Parent** Class

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    if (isChange == TRUE) {  // Here isChange Return NO.
        [self refresh:nil];
    }
}
```

I can't figure out my mistake.

Comment: I normally downvote users who ask for urgency here, especially experienced ones - but the question is otherwise very good so I will refrain on this occasion. Note that as soon as you submit a problem to a volunteer site on the internet, it does not become urgent for anyone else, and it will not be treated with any greater priority than any of the other questions that came in today.

Comment: Do you have Answer for this Question?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is the `Child` inheriting from `Parent` or are they just two random class names (i.e. can you show more of your `.h` file? In the `Child` instance where are you setting `Parent.isChanged = TRUE`?

Comment: Actually I use this Boolean in child class to check Is any Webservice call or not.

Comment: Is it possible without 'prepareForSegue' ?

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but I feel to much of the context is missing. It may help to add some additional code, like how you are presenting the VC's.

Comment: I already specify most of the things like I use Storyboard, I also specify Parent Class Declaration. What you need Please tell me I will Add in My Question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get `TRUE` value because in child class your `alloc` `init`. It create a new `Instance`. It's better to declare this Boolean variable Globally. I will give you the Example.

Declare your variable in `Common.h`

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isChange;
```

Define in `Common.m`

```
- (void)checkIsAnyChange:(BOOL)isChange {
    _isChange = isChange;
    [self updateChangeCount:UIDocumentChangeDone];
}
```

And now use with this `Boolean` in Parent and Child Class for Check.

Answer (score 0):

`[[Parent alloc] init]` creates a new instance of `Parent`.  If you change the value of some property in that instance, there's no reason to expect that the value will also change in some other instance of `Parent`.

If you want to verify what's going on, print the address of the parent when you make the assignment and the value of `self` where you test `isChange`.  If they are not the same, then you're dealing with separate objects.

Comment: is it possible without prepareForSegue method ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.  What does your original question have to do with segues?

Comment: I checked your answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14568595/3378413 Here, I think you use prepareForSegue for data passing.

Comment: Did you understood My Question or not? Please see my comment in Question for what I want.

Comment: I understand that you're changing one `Parent` object and expecting the change to affect a different `Parent` object.  (Otherwise, no, I have no idea why you're talking about "Inherited" data, for example.)